# Как задать геометрию при запуске терминального окна X11

Tags: terminal, x11, xfce4

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как задать геометрию терминального окна при запуске под X11? "Геометрией" будем считать начальное смещение от верхнего левого угла в пикселях, и размер. Размер - желательно в знакоместах по ширине и высоте, если нельзя, хотя бы в пикселях. Иными словами, где тот заветный конфиг?

**Исходные данные:**

- Linux Funtoo
- xfce4
- моноширинные шрифты без разницы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Частичное решение**

"Геометрия" xfce4-terminal храниться в файле ~/.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc, в переменной "MiscDefaultGeometry".

В подвешенном состоянии - вопрос определения смещения окна терминала от верхнего левого угла, если это возможно вообще.

Answer (score 1):

вопрос довольно общий, потому ответ может быть лишь весьма поверхностным.

---

геометрия окна x-клиента указывается в виде `ширина x высота + смещение-по-оси-x + смещение-по-оси-y` (ось `x` — обычно горизонтальная, `y` — обычно вертикальная, координата `+0+0` — это обычно левый верхний угол экрана). например: `100x100+100+100`.

описано это, например, в `$ man X` ([секция `GEOMETRY SPECIFICATIONS`](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.7.0/doc/X.7.html#sect6)).

а вот как эту информацию передать x-клиенту (и возможно ли вообще передать), зависит от самого клиента.

---

например, у программ `gnome-terminal` и `xfce-terminal` (как и у многих других x-клиентов) есть опция `--geometry=значение`:

```
$ gnome-terminal --geometry=100x100+100+100
```

а у программы `xterm` есть опция `-geometry значение`

```
$ xterm -geometry 100x100+100+100
```

---

помимо вышеизложенного стоит упомянуть:

- про файл `~/.Xresources` (`~/.Xdefaults`) и программу `xrdb`, которая может использоваться *de/wm* для загрузки разных ресурсов, в числе которых могут быть и указания о геометрии того или иного окна;
- про то, что *de/wm*-ы могут принимать самостоятельные решения о местоположении создаваемых окон, игнорируя пожелания программы, создающей окно.

Comment: Вопрос - "не общий". Четко задано - Linux Funtoo & xfce4! .XDefaults пробовал, реакции нуль. "игнорируя пожелания программы" - если можно, желательно пруф.

Comment: ... хотя терминалов много ... речь идет о xfce4-terminal 0.8.1

Comment: геометрию терминала смог задать в настройках терминала  (вопрос, где хранится) ... но смещение окна пока не осилил, помогайте, плс)

Comment: @Majestio, *желательно пруф* — [наиболее яркий пример](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%80).

Comment: "тайловые менеждеры", если я не путаюсь с терминологией - это "отдельная", имхо унылая песня. Более того, своеобразное размещение окон - должно быть своеобразным от слова "вообще" (нет там окон, там есть фрэймы).